# How to use loadVideoById

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I got the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to work, but I would like to start the video at a certain time.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
var player = document.getElementById('myPlayer')
player.loadVideoById({
 startSeconds:2,
 endSeconds:4
})
```

```html
<iframe id="myPlayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
               'startSeconds': 5,
               'endSeconds': 60,
               'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

You can also use `player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean)` to get to a time in your video

---

By the way your `player` variable should not be the iframe, in the Tutorial it states just at the beginning that it should be invoked by this:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

You should then use `onPlayerReady` to do your function

Comment: The documentation says "If you do write the <iframe> tag, then when you construct the YT.Player object, you do not need to specify values for the width and height, which are specified as attributes of the <iframe> tag, or the videoId and player parameters, which are are specified in the src URL."

Comment: @PhillipSenn well did `seekTo` help you then?

Comment: I don't know what seekTo is.

Comment: Oh, I see it. "The player does not request the FLV until playVideo() or seekTo() is called."

Comment: @PhillipSenn that should not be a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99246/discussion-between-phillip-senn-and-codeisir).